# Is it possible to make OpenCV matricies with manual input?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, multidimensional-array

I am trying to store the location of four specific points and then putting it into the `cv::fillPoly` function. Currently my locations are stored in a multidimensional array is there a way to convert this or make it straight into a format it accepts?

```
int PointLocationArray[4][2] = {{point1_x, point1_y}, {point2_x, point2_y}, {point3_x, point3_y}, {point4_x, point4_y}};
```

and I'm trying to get it into:

```
cv::fillPoly(newRegion, PointLocationArray, 255);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way is to start with a flat array and then reshape the matrix:

```
static const std::vector<double> data = { 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0 }; // two points
Mat ret = Mat(data).reshape(2, 2);
```

Note: This way, `ret` is a wrapper around `data`. If you would like to copy the data instead, use `Mat(data, true)`.

Another way is to use a combination of `<<` operator and `,` operator for initialization, again, providing the values in a flat manner:

```
Mat ret = (Mat_<double>(2, 2) << 1.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0);
```